# Elasticsearch "register repo" command returns 500 error code but syntax matches the doc (I think)

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have this Python code to register a [Google Cloud Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Storage) (GCS) repository:

```
import requests
from grabconfig import grabconfig

(HOSTS, ign) = grabconfig()

reqHeaders = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}

for h in HOSTS:
    url = f'http://{h}:9200'

    r = requests.put(f'{url}/_snapshot/prod_backup2',
                              '''{ \"type\" : \"gcs\" }, { \"settings\" :  { \"client\" : \"secondary\", \"bucket\" : \"prod_backup2\" },
                                       { \"compress\" : \"true\" }}''',
                              headers=reqHeaders)
    print(r)
    print(r.json())
    r2 = requests.get(f'{url}/_cat/snapshots')
    print(r2)
    print(r2.json())
```

The configuration file I am using is the **prod.py** one:

```
HOSTS = ['10.x.x.x']

BACKUP_REPO = ['prod_backup2']
```

But when I run the code I get this error, always:

```
<Response [500]>
{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'repository_exception', 'reason': '[prod_backup2] repository type [gcs] does not exist'}], 'type': 'repository_exception', 'reason': '[prod_backup2] repository type [gcs] does not exist'}, 'status': 500}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it: the **gcs plugin** was not installed on the server I was targeting.

That's supposed to be fixed by Monday, so I'm on to the next task.